# How to either relocate a frame after it's been realized or assign a browse to another frame in Progress ABL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Ok Progress Virtuoso's,

I'm trying to create a character UI that consists of 6 browses and 6 frames. The vision I currently have is to fire off an ON tab trigger for browse 1 that cues events - show/focus browse 2. Then on tab of browse 2 show/focus browse 3. The next tab trigger is where I am stuck because I want to do the exact same thing with some additional changes to the trigger. Those differences to the trigger involve shifting the location of browse 2/frame 2  to the position of browse 1/frame 1, shifting browse 3/frame3 to the previous position of browse 2/frame, and browse 4/ frame 4 would take 3's position.

Users View = 

**1** (trigger)

1 **2** (trigger) 

1 2 **3** (trigger)

2 3 **4** (trigger)

3 4 **5** (trigger)

4 5 **6** (trigger)

**Bold indicates which frame is in focus.**

I'm fairly sure that's it not possible to assign a static browse to more than one frame. Error 3475 states exactly that...however I want to be sure that is the case? Is it possible to reposition a frame after it's realized? Alternatives approaches/suggestions or any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, but I was able to solve this after looking at frame attributes. Turns out you can reposition a frame with column and row attributes. If you read this...sincere apologies for wasting your time!